# Symfony server ignores catch block in unittest

Tags: php, ldap, phpunit, symfony

At the moment I program some test with phpunit for my symfony project.

I want to test if the server handles a special problem correctly.
The server trys to add a mail to a group. But the group does not exist. So the ldap_mod_add throws an exception. In the code I catch the exception and create the group so that the mail can be added to it.

If I try the code without phpunit it works fine. But with phpunit the server ignores the catch block.

Heres the function

```
//Add
try
{
    ldap_mod_add($this->ldapCon,"mail=$forward,$ldaptree",$forward_info);
}
catch (ContextErrorException $e)
{
    //Check if the forward exist
    $forwardGroup = $this->getForwardForMail($forward);
    if($forwardGroup == [])
    {
        $this->logger->addAlert("Forward $forward does not exist");
        $this->session->getFlashBag()->add("notice","We added the group $forward, because it did not exist.");
        //Create forward and add the first mail
        $this->createForward($forward,$mail);
        return;
    }
    throw new AllreadyInGroupException("User already in forward $forward");
}
```

I disabled the convertWarningsToExceptions option so that the test will go on even if php gives a warning because of the not existing group.

So why does the server ignores the catch block with phpunit?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

Check the actual class of the exception being thrown.

Symfony throws `ContextErrorException` only if its `ErrorHandler` is active, which might not be the case in unit tests run by PHPUnit.

Try catching `\ErrorException` instead.

I'd keep `convertWarningsToExceptions` enabled for consistent behavior. Without it your forwarding logic won't work in tests (the catch block will not get run if only a plain PHP warning is emitted).

Comment: I tried to replace the catch block argument. But this doesn't help. But I know why. ldap_mod_add throws no exception. It only gives back false and creates a warning. The Exceptions came only from Symfony. But what's the best solution? Should I use an if block and a catch block to catch the false and the exception? Or can I disable the warning to exception also in Symfony?

Comment: *It only gives back false* - because you've disabled `convertWarningsToExceptions`.